# Prove that compact sets are closed under arbitrary intersections and finite unions.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I want to show that compact sets are closed under arbitrary intersections and finite unions. I tried the problem and then I noticed that I might be able to take it a step further. Please let me know if I have any mistakes, thanks!

Proof I: Compact sets are closed under finite unions.

Let $\displaystyle A = \{A_1, \dots, A_N\}$ be a set of finitely many compact sets. We know that the elements of $\displaystyle A$ are compact if and only if they are both closed and bounded. It follows that,
\begin{equation*}
\bigcup_{k=1}^N A_k
\end{equation*}
is closed because finite unions of closed sets are closed. Thus we have that the finite union of compacts sets is closed. More over, we have that $M_1, \dots, M_N$ are bounds of $A_1, \dots, A_N$,  respectively. Let $M = \max\{M_1, \dots, M_N\}$, then it follows that
\begin{equation*}
\forall A_k \in A, \forall x\in A_k, |x| \leq M
\end{equation*}
therefore $M$ is a bound of $\bigcup_{k=1}^N A_k$.

We have that $\bigcup_{k=1}^N A_k$ is both closed and bounded, therefore it is compact. Compact sets are compact under finite unions.

Proof II: Compact sets are closed under arbitrary intersections.

Let $\displaystyle A = \{A_1, A_2, A_3, \dots \}$ be an infinite set of compact sets. We know that the elements of $\displaystyle A$ are compact if and only if they are both closed and bounded. It follows that,
\begin{equation*}
\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty A_k 
\end{equation*}
is closed because arbitrary intersections of closed sets are closed. Thus we have that the arbitrary intersection of compact sets is closed.

Is there any way to show that $\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty A_k$ is bounded so that I can say it is compact?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply say that $\cap_{k=1}^\infty A_k \subseteq A_1$. $A_1$ is compact, so it is bounded, and any subset of a bounded subset is bounded. By the way, strictly speaking you have not shown that an *arbitrary* intersection of compact subsets is compact - only that a countable intersection is. This is an immediate fix: just index your intersection by some $I$ rather than by $\mathbb N$. Other than this, your proof is entirely correct!

Comment: Yea I agree. I took out the part about "the arbitrary intersection of compact sets is compact."